# image augmentations using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

i have a question about augmentations...when we use ImageDataGenerator with certain changes like zooming, shifting, and flipping for training.... does this mean the model won't ever see the original (unaugment) image ??

```
# Data Augmentation
  data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.1),
  tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomTranslation(0.1, 0.1)
])

model = Sequential([ data_augmentation,, .........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't know it! The transformations in the data augmentation are applied randomly to each batch of training images, so each time a batch is processed during training, the model sees slightly different versions of the original images. The point is that during the training, an image is processed more and more times (1 for each epoch if the batches are disjoint), so the model will see #epochs slightly different versions of the same image... therefore, one of this slightly different versions
may be the original image (this is unlikely to be true, but it's not impossible).

Comment: thank you very much for the guidance, can you please suggest some reference or some article explaining all this ?

Comment: @sanaullah sorry for the late reply. There are a lot of references on those topics  however, I could not find any that put together the concepts you need (training and data augmentation). You can see https://machinelearningmastery.com/difference-between-a-batch-and-an-epoch/ for explaination about training, specifically the sentence "The batch size is a number of samples processed before the model is updated": each batch is processed (in your case applying data augmentation) randomly and independently from each other.

Comment: highly appreciated  :) concepts are clear now.